# I cannot detach a firebase listener in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

I want to detach a listener when a component unmounts, but cannot find a solution. Whenever I make a change after the component is unmounted, a result is displayed in my browser console.

**Database**

```
var groupUpdate = function(id, callback) {
    return firebase.database().ref('groups/').child(id).on('child_changed', (snapshot) => {
        callback({key: snapshot.key, value: snapshot.val()});
    });
};

module.exports = {
    groupUpdate: groupUpdate
}
```

**Component**

```
export default class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.groupListener = database.groupUpdate(this.props.group.id, (result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }).bind(this);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.groupListener = null;
    }

    render() {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop a listener that you've attached with `on('child_changed'`, call `off('child_changed'` on the same reference or query.

So:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  firebase.database().ref('groups/').child(id).off('child_changed');        
}
```

Or if you prefer to only unregister the specific listener you shared in this code:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  firebase.database().ref('groups/').child(id).off('child_changed', groupUpdate);        
}
```